# LibCharts PHP X-Axis overlap

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Lib charts with mysql. i am getting the bar chart properly but there are too many values on x-axis so they are overlapping and another problem is full names on x-axis are not displaying(Like Ana-Adward. Adward is half displayed on graph). i have checked so many settings but i don't know how to solve this issue. if some one knows please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem with overlapping, made some changes in library to not show every caption.

i use vertical bar chart, so in verticalbarchart.php, after "// Draw caption text on bar" insert:

```
 $roznica1 = abs(($value-$prevvalue1)/$value); 
    $prevvalue1 = $prevvalue;
    $roznica = abs(($value-$prevvalue)/$value); 
    $prevvalue = $value;

    if ((($roznica < 0.2 && strlen($value)>3)||($roznica1 < 0.2 && strlen($value)>5)) && $columnWidth<20) $value="";
```

and before "for ($i = 0; $i < $pointCount; $i++) {" insert:

```
$prevvalue=0;
$prevvalue1=0;
```

it's not neat solution but it works!